# Show only a part of Google Maps display in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already created an app to display the map. But I want to display only a part of map where in when I click on any part of the map my app should zoom to that location where I have clicked and store only that part of map where it is zoomed in (Not entire map)as image file so that I can access it later.

Doing my app it in Android ADT bundle Android v2. I am able to display the entire map and can also zoom to the part of map where I click but I want to capture that zoomed part and store as an image file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a snapshot method for the map you can use, you have to implement a `callback` method and apply it to you map object, here is an example:

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
    SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            try {
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap backBitmap = mView.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                        backBitmap.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/MapScreenShot"
                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    mMap.snapshot(callback);

}
```